# numberpad implemetation

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a number pad like this

[link http://getsetbro.com/img/android-number-input.png](http://getsetbro.com/img/android-number-input.png).

how can I have different font size for number and character.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

got it have to use [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html)